# Can't download more android apis with sdkmanager

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

[image: SDK manager dont respond]

I can't download more android APIs with the sdk manager can't select even platforms or sdk tools or sdk update sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the warning in your screenshot.

The path cannot contain white spaces, and yours does. "Eder Padila", there's a whitespace there. You'll have to set the path to somewhere that doesn't contain whitespaces.